# Create JSON File in local folder

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am working on Windows 8 App, and here my aim is to create a json file with a name and appropriate location in the app from database. And finally, I am using that json file to link to telerik chart and populate data.

In the code snippet below, "GetAutomationPageStaticGroups" is a function in my controller that will retrieve json file.

```
function createJsonFile() {
        WinJS.xhr({
            url: apiUrl + "GetAutomationPageStaticGroups"
        })
};
```

My query is that how to modify above snippet to store that json file with a proper name and at appropriate location within application?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `WinJS.xhr` code that you have shared is working - following code can be used to save it to a file as 'data.json' under application local data.

```
var storage = Windows.Storage;
var data;
WinJS.xhr(({
        url: apiUrl + "GetAutomationPageStaticGroups"
    }).then(function oncomplete(req)
    {
        data = req.responseText;
        return storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.createFileAsync(
                        'data.json',
                        storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting);
    }.then(function oncreatecomplete(file)
    {
         return storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, data,
                storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.utf8);
    }).then(null, function onerror(error)
    {
        // TODO: handle error here
    });
```